# Как преобразовать данные из файла в словарь?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть текстовый файл, содержащий:

```
position=5
quantity=2
position_final=10
quantity_final=2
```

Как эти данные привести в вид `{'position': 5, 'quantity': 2, 'position_final': 10, 'quantity_final': 2}`? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в качестве значений у вас всегда целые числа?

Comment: @MaxU Да, всегда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если числа всегда целые, то:

```
lines = ['position=5',
'quantity=2',
'position_final=10',
'quantity_final=2', 
]
d = dict((k, int(v)) for k,v in (line.split("=") for line in lines))
print(d)
```

Результат:

```
{'position_final': 10, 'position': 5, 'quantity_final': 2, 'quantity': 2}
```

В любом случае, вариант @MaxU более правильный, но там *import re*

Answer (score 2):

можно вот так сделать:

```
import re

def to_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s

s = """
position=5
quantity=2
position_final=10
quantity_final=2
float = 3.1415
str = a free text
"""

d = {k:to_number(v) for k,v in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*([^\n]+)', s)}
```

Результат:

```
In [24]: d
Out[24]:
{'float': 3.1415,
 'position': 5,
 'position_final': 10,
 'quantity': 2,
 'quantity_final': 2,
 'str': 'a free text'}
```